# Can we get back the meta -> main migration path?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, migration

It seems that the meta -> main migration paths were removed. We are a community-driven site, and when someone posts wrongly a question (which happens quite often), I think we are well qualified to judge it well.

I understand the reasoning for removing most user-available migration paths: Many migrated questions are actually quite poor. However, one wouldn't migrate a bad question "within his site", would he? On the other hand, you get people occasionally find meta first, and we're not strict on saying the newcomers that "they're incompetent if they post on meta instead of main".

So I think that this path should be kept.

Comment: If this looks generally popular the mods will raise it with the Powers: I believe it should be relatively easy to get added.